# When importing a key during a yum installation, where is that key stored?

Tags: yum, rpm, gpg

I'm installing a piece of software for which I had to use a third-party repository.  After adding the repository with `rpm -Uvh http://[site]`, I installed with `yum install [package]`.  One of the prompts that came up during installation read:

```
Importing GPG key 0xABCABCAB "Fname Lname <email@somewhere.com>" from /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-somewhere-fname
Is this ok [y/N]: y
```

Does anyone know where this key is stored?  I'm finished with that particular repo and don't want the additional repo/key lingering unnecessarily on my machine.  I've already tried `gpg --list-keys` as both a regular user and root, but the key isn't listed there.

As a work around would simply removing the repo also remove the key associated with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's stored in the rpmdb, with the name of `gpg-pubkey` and the version as the first 8 hexadecimal characters of the fingerprint.

Answer (score 12):

From `rpmkey` manual page:

---

An imported public key is carried in a header, and key ring management is performed  exactly  like  package  management. For example, all currently imported public keys can be displayed by:

```
rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*
```

Details about a specific public key, when imported, can be  displayed  by  querying. Here's information about the Red Hat GPG/DSA key:

```
rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-db42a60e
```

Finally,  public  keys  can be erased after importing just like packages. Here's how to remove the Red Hat GPG/DSA key

```
rpm -e gpg-pubkey-db42a60e
```

---

Comment: thanks for the additional info, I ended up using "rpm -qa gpg-pubkey* | xargs rpm -qi" to see complete info on all the keys (a little sloppy, but it got the job done), then removed the one I didn't want installed.

Answer (score 2):

While Ignacio is correct, it isn't guaranteed ... and may well change in the future. Your best bet is to install the "yum-plugin-keys" package, and use the "yum keys" etc. commands.

Also note that RHEL-6.2+ yum has per. CA keys, so that is already different.