# What are gpg-pubkey* packages?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, rpm, gpg

I compared the packages list reported by RPM and YUM on a CentOS 6 and 7. I noticed the lists were slightly different (same issue with RHEL). See [Listing installed packages with yum and rpm mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28535134/1260896) on how to compare theRPM and YUM lists). The difference was just packages named `gpg-pubkey`:

```
$ rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*
gpg-pubkey-f4a80eb5-53a7ff4b
gpg-pubkey-352c64e5-52ae6884
```

What are those packages? where do they come from? Can I remove those packages?

Comment: cf. [When importing a key during a yum installation, where is that key stored?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28479/when-importing-a-key-during-a-yum-installation-where-is-that-key-stored)

Comment: @maxschlepzig, see question <http://serverfault.com/q/573249/238995> , about where the key are stored.

Answer (score 8):

The packages named `gpg-pubkey*` are fake RPM packages to store and manage the rpm keys. The manpage [rpmkeys(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/rpmkeys.8.html) mention how to list and remove those keys. There is also a YUM addon (package `yum-plugin-keys`):

```
$ yum keys
Key owner                                     Key email                Repo        Key ID
CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key)  security@centos.org      installed   f4a80eb5-53a7ff4b
Fedora EPEL (7)                               epel@fedoraproject.org   installed   352c64e5-52ae6884
keys done
```

Alternatively, you can use RPM to list the keys in a compact view:

```
$ rpm -qa --scripts  gpg-pubkey* --qf '%{Version}-%{Release}  %{Packager}\n'
4a80eb5-53a7ff4b   CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>
352c64e5-52ae6884  Fedora EPEL (7) <epel@fedoraproject.org>
```

When a key is imported by the system administrator (using `rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7`, `rpmkeys` or `yum install`) **the fake package is created** (read [where does rpm install custom gpg keys?](https://serverfault.com/q/573249/238995)).

Removing those keys is a good idea, if you purged all packages from that packager/provider/repo, since it will prevent the system from installing or upgrading any package from that repo.

**Removing those keys is a bad idea, if you haven't purged all packages from that packager/provider/repo**, since it will prevent the system from installing or upgrading any package from that repo.